# Plataformas de pagamento cartão de crédito

Tags: pagamento-online

Quais plataformas de pagamento para cartão de crédito, vocês me indicam além de paypal e pagseguro?

Comment: Por um acaso, as duas mencionadas eu não indicaria pra ninguém. A pergunta é fora do escopo do site, e depende de opinião pessoal, o que não é desejável neste espaço (mais detalhes nos links do quadro amarelo de fechamento). Mas mesmo fechada, o pessoal pode eventualmente sugerir alternativas nos comentários. E falta bem pouco para você poder participar do chat da rede, lá é mais adequado para estes assuntos que fogem do formato Pergunta/Resposta sobre programação em si.

Answer (score -1):

A pergunta não se enquadra na área de programação, contudo abaixo deixo mais algumas que poderá utilizar:

- Netteler
- Skrill
- G2APay

Todas são muito boas e funcionam mais ou menos da mesma forma.